# why is the foot skin still kinda sticking on the ground?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, rigify

[image]

is this happening because of the rig or something else? and how can i fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your *Weight Painting*.

Select the mesh, key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Weight Painting* mode, and key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*. Go to the *3D Viewport > Toolshelf > Brush > Weight: value* and enter 1. Drag the brush over the problem spots. They should change from blue to red and rejoin (jump to) the rest of the mesh (foot).

Comment: ok i will try and let you know

Comment: so should the whole mesh be red?

Comment: No. You can try entering pose mode on the rig, then selecting the mesh, entering weight painting mode on it, and selecting a foot bone. With a foot bone selected, only the foot vertex group should be visible, and then you can paint. Also, if my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: does weight paint fix problems with the head as well? because i can get my head to move, but the neck moves tho and im still messing with the foot so i'll accept if it works full for me.

Comment: Yes, it does all rigging stuff.

Comment: i cover the toe nail parts,but no luck. should make bones for all toes?

Comment: Probably. Also, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the check mark at the top left. It will help me greatly:)